# Spring boot Multi Module project, Rest Services and Web Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, multi-module

we have a Spring boot App that is a Rest Service, it has several microservice to attend other app in our environment, but now we need to create a web app for administrative purpose, so we were thinking of expanding this project making it a multi module project so it can share the repository and other utilities that they will have in common.

the only thing we have concerns is about the spring security config, it is possible that each module has their own security config and still be a single executable jar?

Comment: You can make a common microservice just for security purposes and import it in all other micro services since its a common thing for all. Though it will then become a dependency for them

Comment: the problem is the Rest services have implemented a custom security config using apikey which are processed by custom filters, in the other hand the web app it need to use the old form base authentication, so there is the question it is possible that each module have their own security config?

Comment: As I said you can put common configs in same project and import it in all. Now the api keys and other things are application properties which can be different for different projects. Suppose you have 2 different keys for project A and B so what you do is that you use the same key in the common config code and override their entries in A and B's application properties. So that when common is build with A, it takes api key from A's properties and similarly for B

Answer (score 0):

You can make. Maven or Gradle multi-module project. Common code will be a module without executable. Then you can import that module in all the others.
Yes, different modules can have different security config class.

Comment: we need create two executable modules? (one for REST API and another for the web app), or one executable module and two modules for each functionality with their respective spring security config?